# Drop-down menus and the <li> tag

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, html-lists, parent-child

I am modifying the CSS of an existing web page. The navigation menu is in the form of a list in which the items have a certain background color under normal circumstances and another color when active or hovered-over. The CSS code for this is as follows:

```css
#navigation li a:hover,
#navigation li#active a {
    background: #104E91;
}
```

Some of the menu items (list items, in this case) have drop-down menus with links to sub-pages. I'm trying to make the navigation menu items have the "active" background color not only if they are themselves active, but also if one of their sub-pages is open. Is there any way to implement this? The code for the drop-down menus looks as follows:

```css
#wsite-menus .wsite-menu li:first-child {
    border-top: 1px solid #000;
}

#wsite-menus .wsite-menu li a {
    padding: 8px;
    color: #fff;
    background: #2f2f2f;
    border: 1px solid #4b4b4b;
    border-top: none;
}

#wsite-menus .wsite-menu li a:hover {
    background: #4b4b4b;
}
```

I suspect that the way to bring this about would be to modify the first of the two above blocks of code to read as follows:

```css
#navigation li a:hover,
**#navigation li#active child,**
#navigation li#active a {
    background: #104E91;
}
```

or something similar, but I can't figure out the exact syntax. Is there a way an open child page can make the parent page look active in the navigation menu?

The HTML is as follows:

```
<div id = "navigation">
    <ul class = "wsite-menu-default">
        <span id = "Span1" class = "wsite-nav-handle"> style="display:                 inline;">
          <li class="w-menu-item  wsite-nav-0" style="position: relative;">
```

... and so on, there are a number of list items. I guess I should create a separate span that imparts an active background color to a list item, and, on each child page, put that span around the list item that is responsible for the page's parent's menu item.

Comment: Show HTML, because it's difficult to say where `#wsite-menus` is.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't show any HTML, so I made up some of my own. I didn't use your tags of the same reason.

HTML:

```
<nav>
  <a href="#"><li>Home</li></a>
  <a href="#">
    <li>Dropdown
    <div class="dropdown">
      <div class="dropdown-inner">
        <a>Menu</a>
        <a>Number</a>
        <a>3</a>
    </div>
    </li>
  </a>
  <a href="#"><li>About</li></a>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
nav li {
  list-style:none;
  display:inline-block;
  text-align:center;
  background:#222;
  color:#FFF;
  width:100px;
  padding:10px 20px
}

nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color:#FFF;
}

nav li div.dropdown {
  display:block;
  position:absolute
}

nav li div.dropdown .dropdown-inner {
  right:20px; /* Equal to li padding Y */
  width:100px; /* Equal to li width */
  padding:10px 20px; /* Equal to li padding X */
  background:#333;
  top:10px;
  position:relative
}

nav li span.dropdown a {
  display:block;
}
```

Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bzIGl

Comment: Thank you! I've updated my original posting to include some of the HTML. It now seems, though, that there is no way to do this except editing the HTML on each child page to affect the appearance of the menu item.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're having is because you're assigning the background color to the `<a>` tag instead of `<li>` tag. When you exit a parent `<li>` item and move down to a child `<li>` element, you've technically left the `<a>` and so the background color reverts correctly. If however you apply the background color to the `<li>` tag, rolling over any child list items will keep the active state on the parent `<li>` item.

Comment: What I was trying to figure out, though, was not how to make the parent item still appear active when hovering over child items, but how to make it appear active when one of the child pages is open.